# Cannot deploy .Net DLL on machines other than the original compile machine

Tags: .net, excel, visual-studio, vba, dll

I have written a VB.NET Class Library in Visual Studio 2010 Express.  I made sure to select "Make assembly COM-Visible" on the Properties-->Application-->Assembly Information tab.  I also made sure to select "Register for COM Interop" on the compile tab of the properties window.

The resulting DLL works fine on the machine that compiled the project.  The DLL is intended to do some heavy processing on a few input arrays from Excel and return an output array.  I am able to add a reference to the DLL in VBA and use the functionality just fine.

I cannot figure out how to install the DLL on other machines.  I made sure to update .NET to the current version on the deployment machine.  I then run the following batch file:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe "C:\Users\Public\DRAPERLibrary.dll" /codebase /tlb:DRAPERLibrary.tlb

This call to RegAsm comes back with no errors.

I can see where the Windows registry has some new references to this DLL but I can't see the DLL in Excel.  If I manually browse to the DLL it comes back with the error "Can't add a reference to the specified file".

Where have I gone wrong here?  What is Visual Studio doing to create an Excel reference?  Is there something I can add to my batch file to cause Excel to recognize this DLL as an available reference in VBA?

Thanks so much for taking the time to respond.

Comment: You probably should not use the 64-bit version of Regasm.exe, most Office installs are 32-bit.  Use Framework, not Framework64.

Comment: I highly recommend using installshield limited or another similar product to create an installer instead of the batch file route. Life is *much* simpler that way.

Comment: @HansPassant Using the 32bit version of Regasm caused the DLL to show up in the VBA References list; however, now when I run the VBA code on the deployment machine I receive the error "ActiveX component can't create object".  This macro does work on the development machine.

Comment: Update:  I had to go back to my development machine and make sure I had everything working correctly on that end.  I changed the target CPU to "AnyCPU" and the DLL is working on the development machine.  I went ahead and changed the name of the assembly, recompiled, and attempted to deploy the DLL on the new machine.  After changing the RegAsm directory from Framework64 to Framework I am seeing the DLL in my VBA references.  When I go to access the DLL through Excel I am getting a new error now.  "Run -time error '-2147467259(80004005)':  Automation error  Unspecified error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the DLL working on other machines today.  I made a few mistakes initially which caused the DLL to fail.  The origin of my problem was caused by registering the DLL using the 64 bit version of RegAsm instead of the 32 bit version.  The order of operations listed below is what finally got this sorted out.

- Remove any old DRAPERLibrary references in VBA
- Completely unregister the DLL using RegAsm with the /u argument
- Register the new DLL using the 32 bit version of RegAsm because I am working with a 32 bit version of Excel (\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ instead of \Microsoft.NET\Framework64)
- Select the reference to the new DRAPERLibrary in VBA
- Update the module code to reflect the latest DLL version number

Thanks to @HansPassant for helping me figure all of this out.